# Can you identify this animal?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

It was in the bathroom, 2cm in lenght (or so). It has two small antenas on the head. I live on Balkan peninsula, inland.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a millipede, maybe a centipede. I can't count the legs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a European Millipede.

[image: european millipede]

I found this picture by searching European Millipede. Obviously there are different types - and this is the one you have. 
Here is a wiki link I found: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindroiulus

I think your specifically is a [*Cylindroiulus britannicus*](https://www.google.com/search?q=cylindroiulus+britannicus&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjpurIgNXMAhVIPCYKHaLvA3cQvwUIGigA&biw=1440&bih=805)

.

Comment: do you have any reference to add; what made you think that this is a european millipede?

Comment: Sure. I will edit the post.

Comment: Why would *C. **britannicus*** be in the Balkans? I couldn't find a habitat range for the species, but its name would suggests otherwise.

Comment: @MarchHo- I think they were imported somehow. I am not sure, but I can look that up.

Comment: It is certainly a millipede, but I doubt it is C. britannicus. They live in natural habitat, like forest floors. In the balkan, greece and cyprus, there is a millipede that commonly lives near and in houses, I have encountered it often. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find the name (yet).

Comment: @RHA, same - but it looked very, very similar so I assumed that that was it...